# How to use mutate rowwise with complex row operation?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

How can I use mutate to achieve the below?

```
bd_diag_date <- df %>%
  apply(1, function(dates) last(na.omit(dates))) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  `colnames<-`("diag_date")
```

I tried this below but didn't work. I can't find out why and it says `Error: Column 'diagnosis_date' is of unsupported type symbol`. Should I assume mutate takes any function operation that can apply to a vector? If not, then what kind of operation does it accept?

```
bd_diag_date <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  {mutate(., diag_date=last(na.omit(all_vars(.))))}
```

I also have a more general questions. That is how can I debug this? Every time I encounter this problem I have to google stack exchange but I feel like this isn't the right way to improve my dplyr skill.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pmap`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   mutate(diag_date = pmap(., ~ last(na.omit(c(...)))))
```

If the columns are `numeric`, we can use `pmap_dbl`, simply using `pmap` returns a `list` column

```
df %>%
       mutate(diag_date = pmap_dbl(., ~ last(na.omit(c(...)))))
#  col1 col2 col3 diag_date
#1    1   NA    2         2
#2   NA    2   NA         2
#3    3    4   NA         4
```

If we need to return only a single column, use `transmute`

```
df %>%
  transmute(diag_date = pmap_dbl(., ~ last(na.omit(c(...)))))
```

---

Or with `group_split` and `map`

```
df %>% 
     group_split(grp = row_number(), keep = FALSE) %>%
     map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
            transmute(diag_date = last(na.omit(unlist(.)))))
```

---

Or using `base R` with `max.col`

```
df$diag_date <- df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(!is.na(df), 'last'))]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, NA, 3), col2 = c(NA, 2, 4), col3 = c(2, NA, NA))
```

Comment: The former gives `Error: Column 'diagnosis_date' must be length 1 (the group size), not 0`

Comment: @ZHU i couldn't test without a small example.  Please use `dput` to show a small example

Comment: @ZHU I updated with a reproducible example and it is working for me

Comment: So can I ask why the first solution you suggested didn't work?

Comment: @ZHU That solution is deleted now

Comment: Then can I ask why the solution I provided didn't work? Also, how should I debug this?

Comment: @ZHU 1) `mutate` doesn't have `all_vars` argument, 2) the `.` is  still a data.frame with one row, `last` is applied on `na.omit`, which would remove the row if there is. a single NA in that row.  Instead, it should be `unlist`ed, but `unlist`ing on the `rowwise`, would also recursively unlist the whole column, breaking the grouping,

Comment: Also, `rowwise` is slow compared to `pmap/map`